# DICOM; doing multiplannar reconstruction and displaying on web

Tags: applet, dicom

Good people,

I have a project that involves displaying CT scans on the web. We currently have generated flythru videos and viewing of individual slices, as well as download feature.

Now, the problem: my client has requsted the possibility to do multiplannar reconstuction and displaying it on the web. The reconstruction on its own can be done, but really depends on what kind of format the viewer will take.

The only solution I can find on the web is the EViewBox, which is an Java applet from the late 90's. I can't find any recent examples, and the examples I see are not suitable.

I looking for an applet that downloads the scan and does the MPR on the client side. Both Java and Flash is acceptable.

I'm looking for something that gives the same functionality like the applet in the link below:

http://digimorph.org/specimens/Simosuchus_clarki/applet/inspector.phtml

Any experiences and ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution where the scan is downloaded to the client and the client performs the MPR in some applet, or where the MPR is generated on the server and the client never deals with anything more complex than an <img> ?

Comment: i second timday.  @PTM, what exactly are you looking for?  Btw, only the top right, bottom left and right are the 3 planes to MPR. the figure on TOP LEFT looks to me is a 3D rendering of the CT scans.

Comment: Sorry for not making that clear; I want the MPR to be done on the client side, through an applet. I've also updated the link to show more or less exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I note you say Applet, which to be honest, I'm not sure about. If SilverLight is acceptable, I know there are efforts to create a ClearCanvas (http://www.clearcanvas.ca) SilverLight viewer online. ClearCanvas can handle that, so I assume the web client could too.